# FileOutputStream illegalArgumentException "/" not allowed

Tags: android, database, fileoutputstream, illegalargumentexception, internal-storage

I've spent hours trying to figure this out.
I am trying to write an image that gets downloaded to my internal android folder.
The only problem is that i need different images to get stored in subdirectories of the application data folder because they are connected to objects which have the same ID as the folder name.
I understand from the documentation that FileOutputStream doesn't allow to output to subdirectories but only to the "root" app data folder.
Is there a workaround to this?
This is my code:

```
 public static void writeImageToInternal(byte[] inImg, String FolderName, Context ctx) {

    File file = new File(ctx.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/img/" + FolderName);
    if (!file.exists())
        file.mkdirs();

    int Name= 0;
    // TODO: Find Available Name
    File mypath = new File(file, FolderName + Name + ".png");
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;
    try {
        // mypath.createNewFile();
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(inImg, 0, inImg.length).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As mentioned above the reason for this is that when objects are loaded from a database the applications searches for a folder named like the object id and gives back all images in that folder.
Is there any way to get this to work?

And secondly,
since i am connecting different images to specific objects would it be better to save my images as BLOBS in a database instead?
I also already have a database on my app and i can't use the same one because the data database gets backed up on a server and i don't want the images getting copied to.
They are many image files involved so if the database implementation is better is it possible to save a database to external storage?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: FIleOutputStream is a java class, not an Android class.  It has no restrictions on subdirectories except that you must have write permissions and the directory must already exist.  Is your problem that you haven't created the directory yet maybe?

Comment: no I tryed with
   mypath.createNewFile(); and then commented it out because nothing changed. I thought it had the same restrictions as openFileOutput() 
But i still can't find the problem.

Comment: I don't think createNewFile creates the directories.  I think it only makes the file if the directory already exists.

Comment: Ok,i i figured that the problem was actually that BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(inImg, 0, inImg.length)
was giving a null value to compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut); THis means that the bitmap is not decodable. Any reason for this to happen? It is a png downloaded from a specific hardcoded url so i'm sure it's downloading the right file.